# 2 application users with different dbContexts

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have an web app with 2 different application users:

```
JobSeekerUser
EmployerUser
```

also I have the following dbContexts:

```
JobSeekerAppDbContext
EmployerAppDbContext
```

In Startup, I have the following config:

```
   services.AddIdentity<DataAccess.JobSeekerUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.Password.RequiredLength = 10).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataAccess.JobSeekerAppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentity<DataAccess.EmployerUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.Password.RequiredLength = 10).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataAccess.EmployerAppDbContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Can I do this? If yes? How do I tell Identity which DBContext to retrieve att every point(`JobSeekerAccountController`, `EmployerAccountController`)?

Comment: Have you tried it before posting the question? Each DbContext has it's own type, so whats your problem?

Comment: @Tseng adding 2 identity services didnt work

Comment: Identity is not designed for such use case. Just add the user to either role "JobSeeker" or "Employer".

Comment: @sprengo  split the apis in seperate projects, JobSeeer.Api and Employer.Api. Thanks